# convertion of datatable/dataset to a given array

Tags: c#, spatial-query

I am referring one tutorial which is in php.I am converting in into C#.The thing is that they have used

my query in this

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_Union(
    ST_Difference(
      ST_Buffer(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326), 30),
      ST_Envelope(
        ST_Buffer(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326), 10)
      )
    ),
    ST_Envelope(
        ST_Buffer(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-55 -55)', 4326), 10)
      )
  )
);
```

the result after executing in the postgresql is

```
"MULTIPOLYGON(((30 0,29.4235584120969 -5.85270966048384,27.7163859753386 -11.4805029709527,24.9440883690764 -16.6671069905881,21.2132034355964 -21.2132034355964,16.6671069905881 -24.9440883690763,11.4805029709527 -27.7163859753386,5.85270966048389 -29.4235584120969,4.84662765649901e-014 -30,-5.85270966048379 -29.4235584120969,-11.4805029709526 -27.7163859753386,-16.667106990588 -24.9440883690764,-21.2132034355964 -21.2132034355965,-24.9440883690763 -16.6671069905881,-27.7163859753386 -11.4805029709528,-29.4235584120969 -5.85270966048394,-30 -9.69325531299803e-014,-29.4235584120969 5.85270966048375,-27.7163859753386 11.4805029709526,-24.9440883690764 16.667106990588,-21.2132034355965 21.2132034355963,-16.6671069905882 24.9440883690763,-11.4805029709528 27.7163859753386,-5.85270966048396 29.4235584120969,-1.12092138956216e-013 30,5.85270966048374 29.4235584120969,11.4805029709526 27.7163859753386,16.667106990588 24.9440883690764,21.2132034355964 21.2132034355965,24.9440883690763 16.6671069905881,27.7163859753386 11.4805029709528,29.4235584120969 5.85270966048391,30 0),(-10 -10,10 -10,10 10,-10 10,-10 -10)),((-65 -65,-65 -45,-45 -45,-45 -65,-65 -65)))";
```

Now After this my php do the conversion of this is array(which converts the given system datatable into array)

```
$arr = pg_fetch_array($res);
```

Now i want to write similar function which php do?
But unable to convert correctly

my function look like this

```
public Array FetchArray(DataTable Dt)
    {
        int[] array;
        Array arr = new Array[];
        Array converted = new Array(Dt.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in Dt.Rows)
        {
            arr.Add(row);//here it should convert the system DataTable into sytem array
        }
        return arr;

    }
```

somebody Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework are you working with?

Comment: @tstuts I am using Microsoft visual Studio 2010 .net version 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`System.Data.DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class has an [`ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property that returns the row's values in an array (of type `object`)

So, maybe the following example will help you get where you're trying to go:

```
foreach (DataRow row in Dt.Rows)
{
    object[] values = row.ItemArray;
}
```

Comment: You Mean to Say.Now My Function look like this
 public object FetchArray(DataTable Dt)
    {
      object [] rowarray = new object[2];
        //Array arr = new Array[Dt.Rows.Count];
       foreach (DataRow row in Dt.Rows)
        {
           object[] values = row.ItemArray;
          
        }
     return rowarray;

    }

Comment: Correcting Myself.
Now MY Function Should look like this
[code]
 public DataTable FetchArray(DataTable Dt)
    {
      object [] rowarray = new object[2];

      DataRow relation;
        //Array arr = new Array[Dt.Rows.Count];
       foreach (DataRow row in Dt.Rows)
        {
           object[] values = row.ItemArray;
           relation = Dt.NewRow();
           relation.ItemArray = values;
           Dt.Rows.Add(relation);
        }
     return Dt;

    }[code]

Comment: It's very hard to understand from your code examples what exactly you are trying to return from this method.  The `pg_fetch_array` PHP function you referred to simply returns the values in the row as an array, which `row.ItemArray` would be similar to in C#.  What else are you wanting to do?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I Just want to write the code parallel to php_fetch_array would work similar to this in C# on calling my function Fetcharray.Thats why trying to convert resultant DataTable into array and returning it.